# Al ejecutar un APK en el celular aparece el error "Unable to load script...". React-Native

Tags: react-native

Al ejecutar la aplicación desde el celular aparece un errror, aunque desde el emulador no aparece.

El error es el siguiente:

> Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running aMetro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.

[image: Error al ejecutar APK en el celular]

Answer (score 0):

¿Tienes corriendo el Metro server ?, de no ser así tiene que correr este comando `react-native start` en tu terminal para que habilites el servidor Metro, que el que carga los archivos compilado de react-native a la app por vía http.

Tambien debes configurar las configuraciones de desarrollo de tu dispositivo, para ello debes abrir una terminal e introducir el siguiente comando `adbshell input keyevent 82` (esto si estas en android ^5) para entrar al menu de desarrollador, luego selecionas la opcion `Dev Settings`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecionas la ultima opciones que se representa en la imagen, e introduces la IP de tu computador. Claramente que ambos equipos deben estar conectados a la misma red.

Buenos, espero que esto te ayude en algo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener corriendo, en otra consola el siguiente comando: `react-native start` o `npm start` .. Son similares